# How to update Group Policy Templates in for Local Computer?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

Are the Administrative Templates downloaded from the MS website (for example, the 21H1 templates can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103124) meant to update just a single, local computer? Or are they meant to update templates on a Central Store Server that handles multiple computers on a network? Or both?

If the Administrative Templates are used to update a local computer, what the correct procedure for doing so? When the Administrative Template MSI files downloaded from MS are executed, the newest template files are copied into the Program Files directory only. Does the user have to manually copy the .admx and .adml files into the %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions folder?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually update the Administrator templates if you keep your system updated. The templates exist for systems that wouldn't otherwise have them installed (Windows 7, Windows 8, ect).

Comment: My original post had more information but was forced to shorten and make the questions "focused" by a moderator. I am running Win10 Education 21H1 64 bit. Almost all of the *.admx/*.adml files from the %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions folder are newer than the corresponding files in MS Administrative Template download except for feeds.admx, searchocr.admx, windowsmediadrm.admx and windowsmediaplayer.admx, in which case the downloaded templates are newer. With that in mind, I am assuming I need to just manually update the older files, correct?

Comment: And, the MS Administrative Template download contains grouppolicypreferences.admx and mmcsnapins2.admx, which are not present in the local %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions folder. I am guessing those templates are for servers/network admins, right?

Comment: You shouldn't have to manually update the templates since you are already running 21H1 are you finding that your group policy editor is missing policies that should otherwise exist?  If I am not mistaken, the templates files are basically XML files, so you can compare them with your favorite program.  Are you looking to set polices against [MMC](https://github.com/defendthehoneypot/policydefinitions/blob/master/MMCSnapIns2.admx)?  Had you no delete your original question I was going to answer it by the way.  *My work was lost when you deleted it.*

Comment: The feeds.admx, searchocr.admx, windowsmediadrm.admx and windowsmediaplayer.admx files are present but newer versions (later modified dates) are available from the Administrative Templates download from MS. I am guessing I should update the older .admx and .adml files in the %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions folder with the newer versions provided by MS, but I am asking for confirmation. If so, how do I update? I am guessing you backup the old files and copy the new files, but %systemroot%\PolicDefinitions is a protected folder, with TrustedInstaller (or System) as owner.

Comment: Just replace the files.  Are you planning to use the policies within those templates?

Comment: Probably just the WMP related templates. Now the next question. The templates in %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions are protected from writing or deleting. I believe the folder has TrustedInstaller (or System) as the owner but I am a user (with Admin privileges) and cannot move or delete or overwrite the existing files. What is the best way to move out ( and backup ) the old templates and replace with new templates? I was thinking of changing owner to User, perform the file operation, and change the owner back to TrustedInstaller or log into the built in Admin account to perform the operations.

Comment: When I installed the Administrator Templates for Edge a few months back i had no problem modifying files within `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions`.  Of course I wasn't replacing files only adding the files to the folder.  It's still not clear the reason you think the administrator templates even need to be updated on your system.  *They should already be current.*  I worked 13 hours yesterday, my intention was to compare some of the files, but I simply didn't have it in me to do so.

Comment: That was my initial question as to whether I needed to update the Win10 GPO templates with those updated Admin templates from the MS site. I extracted the MS download and compared the modified date of the downloaded templates from MS to the templates in %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions folder and found that Windows had the most current templates EXCEPT for  feeds.admx, searchocr.admx, windowsmediadrm.admx and windowsmediaplayer.admx (and the corresponding *.adml files). So my question refined itself to: do the out of date templates need to be updated?

Comment: You only need to install the missing templates if those policies are going to be configure.  `.admx` files go into `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions` while `. adml` files go into `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\[APPROPRIATE LANGUAGE/LOCALE]`

Comment: Understood. The only templates I am interested in using are the two involving WMP. So what would be the appropriate way to update these templates since %systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions is a protected folder? I cannot just rename or remove the templates to be updates, even with Admin privileges.

Comment: Just copy and paste the files into the appropriate folder.  You have indicate that `feeds.admx, searchocr.admx, windowsmediadrm.admx and windowsmediaplayer.admx` were missing from the `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions` folder

Comment: No, you misunderstood.  The files feeds.admx, searchocr.admx, windowsmediadrm.admx and windowsmediaplayer.admx are already present. But the corresponding files from the Admin templates update from MS are newer. I want to replace the older files with the newer files but older files are protected with Trusted Installer as the owner. How do I update in that case?